# Material dialog library doesn't work with Cyrillic alphabet

Tags: android, dialog, material-design, cyrillic

I'm trying to utilize [this](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs#input-dialogs) library for creating dialog styled with material design, but it seems not to work with Cyrillic alphabet (it works just fine when I'm typing something with Roman alphabet). 
My code:

```
        new MaterialDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this)
              .title("Добавить в список")
              .inputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT)
              .input("Имя", null, new MaterialDialog.InputCallback() {
                 @Override
                 public void onInput(MaterialDialog dialog, CharSequence input) {
                   save(input);
                 }
              }).show();
```

What am I doing wrong? Or should I use another library for creating material dialog? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe just the font you're using doesn't have needed characters? What do you see, when you use Cyrilics?

Comment: You are right, I've tried to use default alert dialog and I cannot type there cyrillic chars, although if I set some text in advance, It dispplayed. I'm confused